# Moving inetpub from C to D

Tags: iis

A security audit suggested we move the directory IIS is serving the websites to another location - from `C` drive to `D` drive, just in case there are DDoS attacks, so that it will not directly affect the server drive.

How should I properly do it? Is it just as simple as moving the inetpub directory from C to D and changing the website paths?

Or there's a more "safe" method to do it?

I'm just worried that if I simply move the folder and change paths, some settings in IIS will still use the original path (`C:/inetpub/`) for setting things up.

So I wanted to know what is the best way to do it

Comment: I am familliar with this recommendation, though using it as a means to degrade more gracefully when capacity is overrun is a new one by me. I suppose it makes sense. I do know that moving the webroot to a non-system drive is recommended do to the potential for pathing exploits, but I am curious what advice/audit/benchmark contained that recommendation. could you point me to it?

Comment: They really searched for every little possible risk and categorized it by the probability and damage factor. This one was low on both. I tried to translate what they wrote as best as I could: `The apps are stored in the OS drive. In case of multiple attacks on the server, it may overload the disk, causing the server to be unavailable.
Recommendations: Place the apps in a separate drive from the OS drive, and give the right permissions to the containing folders (System and Administrators)`. The last part is funny because one of the answers mentioned NOT to give permissions to `SYSTEM`

Comment: You can set a quota for that user/group (obviously not system/administrators), in order to prevent this kind of issue (disk full).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any security issue regarding the directory location.

The only thing that matters is the user account, under which the IIS service is running. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731360/9430820) for more details. TL;DR, it should **not** be SYSTEM.

Comment: There have been historical exploits in pathing that could allow an attacker to enumerate and in some cases read/execute files outside of inetpub (and most of c:\windows is readable by all users). since its right next to the windows system directory at a predictable path, should one of these vulnerabilities be reintroduced, it is in fact a good idea to move it.

Answer (score 1):

This security audit suggestion doesn't make much sense.

Moving a website elsewhere from `inetpub` is in itself a dangerous
operation regarding security, as a new folder would need to have exactly
the right permissions to avoid breakouts.
Using a folder that is not secure enough is a big danger.

The folder `inetpub` as set up by Windows is well-protected by its
permissions and is very safe to use. For a folder on D, you will
need to duplicate exactly these permissions, otherwise you will be
introducing new vulnerabilities.

Comment: CIS benchmarks for IIS do indicate you should move the inetpub directory: https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/microsoft_iis . see here for a historical exploit in encoding that allowed the predictable location of c:\inetpub to traverse paths outside of the webroot. Don't get me wrong, this is an old issue, but could be reintroduced by new bugs in IIS or windows at any time: https://www.giac.org/paper/gcih/115/iis-unicode-exploit/101163

Comment: @FrankThomas: I've seen on this site posters that have moved it and had permissions problems afterward, which is why I don't advise it if one doesn't fully know how to.